# strerror_r buffer always null terminated

Tags: c, posix, glibc

Is this code safe:

```
strerror_r(errcode,buffer,length);
printf("Error: %s",buffer);
```

That is, can I trust buffer to be null terminated in case the buffer is to small? From the man page:

> The XSI-compliant strerror_r() is preferred for portable applications. It returns the error string in the user-supplied buffer buf of length buflen.
>
> The **GNU-specific** strerror_r() returns a pointer to a string containing the error message. This may be either a pointer to a string that the function stores in buf, or a pointer to some (immutable) static string (in which case buf is unused).  If the  function stores  a  string in buf, then at most buflen bytes are stored (the string may be   truncated if buflen is too small and errnum is unknown). **The string always includes a terminating null byte ('\0')**.

Am I right that if I use the XSI-compliant version, it may happen that *buffer* is not null terminated.

Comment: @yellowantphil RHEL 5.4 is not relevant, unless the kernel has been upgraded to version 2.6.36, and gcc to 4.8.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using the POSIX `strerror_r` and it returns non-zero, I’m not sure that you can assume that anything at all is in `buffer`. You can check `man 3p strerror` for the POSIX function description, but it doesn’t say what happens to `buffer` if `length` isn’t large enough.

Maybe some other part of the POSIX standard says what happens in situations like this, but I suspect that it isn’t specified. I would check the return value of `strerror_r`, and not use `buffer` if it’s non-zero, just to be safe.

On two systems where I tried this, the compiler copied the error message into the buffer and truncated it with a NUL byte. On RHEL 5.4, `strerror_r` did not modify `buffer` if its size was too small. In that case, `buffer` could be anything, if you didn't initialize it before caling `sterror_r`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the changelog for xpg-strerror.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=history;f=string/xpg-strerror.c;h=36e2548dbb7917f932cd9287a1e36f576bf00a16;hb=9a869d822025be8e43b78234997b10bf0cf9d859):

```
2011-05-21  Ulrich Drepper  Always fill output buffer in XPG strerror function  blob | commitdiff | diff to current
2010-12-25  Ulrich Drepper  Change XPG-compliant strerror_r function to return...   blob | commitdiff | diff to current
```

So if I assume a decent version of glibc, everything seems to be fine. Unless some guy reverts the change.